# Filamentphp V3 Insert data into pivot tables

Tags: pivot-table, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am having issues with inserting data into a pivot table. My pivot table is setup as follows:

```
Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignIdFor(Event::class);
            $table->foreignIdFor(Stand::class);
            $table->foreignIdFor(Level::class);
            $table->foreignIdFor(User::class);
        });
```

and I have the following select lists setup in my form where the user selects the stand, level and then the users (which is a multiple select list)

```
Select::make('stand')
                                ->relationship('users')
                                ->options(Stand::pluck("name", "id"))
                                ->required()
                                ->label('Stand'),
                            Select::make('level')
                                ->relationship('users')
                                ->options(Level::pluck("name", "id"))
                                ->required()
                                ->label('Level'),
                            Select::make('user')
                                ->relationship('users')
                                ->options(User::pluck("name", "id"))
                                ->multiple()
                                ->required()
                                ->label('Runners')
                                ->searchable()
```

When I save it only attempts to sabe the event_id and User_id only

My relationship is setup as follows

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'event_user')->withPivot(['stand_id', 'level_id']);
    }
```

How can I get it to insert all ids?

Comment: The way you're implementing it right now it won't work out of the box, to use pivot attributes have a look at https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/relation-managers#creating-with-pivot-attributes. If you want to do it your way you would have to mutate your data before creating/updating/saving and for each user record add the level_id and stand_id yourself, see https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/repeater#mutating-related-item-data-before-creating

Comment: Thanks for your response Tom. No matter what I try, nothing works. If I mutate the data it doesn't append the data I want. I keep getting the error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'stand_id' doesn't have a default value
INSERT INTO `event_user` (`event_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (6, 2) stand_id and level_id never appear

Comment: I have sort of solved the problem by creating a pivot model and provided a hasMany relationship with all stand, level and user models. This options works great if you select a single user, but where it doesn't work is when you want to select multipe user